# how to write a sports game scene?

Tags: creative-writing, plot, planning

The main character is on a sports team, and I want to describe games, but I don't know how to without having to explain every point or without explaining it enough.  I want it to be a page or two long the game itself, but have no idea how to write it so it doesn't get boring for the reader or seem rushed and unplanned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on the highlights. Whenever you watch a game recap on television, they don't replay the entire game. Instead, they just show you the highlights. You need to do the same with your writing. Identify three or four crucial elements within the game itself: someone scoring, someone getting hurt, or someone making an important save. If you focus on those crucial elements and provide enough detail for the reader to be drawn into them, then you should be able to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

While you did find your chosen answer already, I still have another option in mind: use the commentators to describe what happened. If there are any at all... Well, when this is some fantasy sport in an environment where no television or radio broadcast is available, that not an option. But if you have such kind of devices in your world, feel free to have two commentators speaking about it.

When this is a sport that is non-real and would need much explanation to make sense to the reader, let these guys spending half of the time sharing the latest gossip about the number 5 (your protagonist) and the ladies or boys he or she was seen last time...

...and oh, now that huge brute from the other team did a bad foul to him. Looks like he needs a new leg soon, isn't he, Larry?

That's right, Scott, but Mr Velentine, who happen to be the trainer of him, also own a cybernetic replacement, and he feels good about it.

But what is now? Did they just flat the ball? Well, Larry, this is going to be a long game tonight. And now for a consumer hint proudly provided by our sponsor "Synty Limbs inc."

Comment: I had trouble understanding some of the things you were saying. Please reread your answer and consider whether you stated your thoughts clearly.